# Unable to get task failure, success and retry notifications in GCP composer using Sendgrid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, sendgrid, google-cloud-composer, email-notifications

I want to receive an email notification for task success, failure and retry in GCP composer using Sendgrid.

Currently, all the tasks in my DAG are running successfully. I want to receive notification in that case.

Also when certain tasks are failing or retrying, I want to get those notifications as well. I did the following steps and didn't receive any notification when I forced a task to fail.

1. Created GCP Composer environment, added environment variables.

```
SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM : abc@gmail.com

SENDGRID_API_KEY :
```

2. Created following DAG.

```py
import json
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_check_operator import BigQueryCheckOperator
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,    
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 30),
    'email': ['abc@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),

}


schedule_interval = "05 23 * * *"


dag = DAG(
    'DAG_NAME', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval
    )

# Config variables
BQ_CONN_ID = ""
BQ_PROJECT = ""
BQ_DATASET = ""

## Task 1
t1 = BigQueryCheckOperator(----)

## Task 2
t2 = BigQueryCheckOperator(----)

## Task 3
t3 = BigQueryOperator(----)

t4  = EmailOperator(
        task_id='send_email',
        to='abc@gmail.com',
        subject='Airflow Alert',
        html_content=""" <h3>Email Test</h3> """,
        dag=dag

    )
# Setting up Dependencies
t1>>t2>>t3>>t4
```

Am I missing anything? Please tell me what needs to be done, thanks.

Comment: Hi! Please, specify which version of Composer, Airflow and Sendgrid you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to check which versions of Composer and Sendgrid you are using.

For instance, the latest version of Sendgrid supported on `airflow-1.10.3` is `v5.6.0`. You can refer to the the airflow's [setup.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/setup.py#L225) for what dependencies are installed for a specific airflow version.

I recommend you to check [the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#configuring_sendgrid_email_services) for setting up Sendgrid with Cloud Composer once again. Make sure of a few things:

- You set up the environment variables as the guide says, to configure Sendgrid as your email server, you need to obtain your `SENDGRID_API_KEY` (have you generate it with right permission? At a minimum, the key must have `Mail send` permissions to send email) and `SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM`(is the structure correct? `noreply-composer@`) as environment variables.
- In your `airflow.cfg` file, check if `email_backend` variable is set to use Sendgrid:

```
email_backend = airflow.contrib.utils.sendgrid.send_email
```

- Try sending a test DAG, as the guide says, for example you can use this:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'owner': 'name.surname',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email': ['name.surname@company.com'],
}

dag = DAG(
    'mail-test',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    default_args=default_args,
)

send_mail = EmailOperator(
    task_id='sendmail',
    to='name.surname@company.com',
    subject='TEST Mail from Cloud Composer',
    html_content='Mail Contents',
    dag=dag,
)

failed_bash = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_bash',
    bash_command='exit 1',
    dag=dag,
)

send_mail >> failed_bash
```

Additionally, please check the spam filter in your email client. If that continues to fail, I'd then start suspecting a firewall rule (if you have edited them) may be causing the issue.

Let me know about the results. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped .